# Is it bad to use multiple dimens.xml files with dififrent width for storing size variables in android?

Tags: android

Is it bad practice to use multiple `dimens.xml` files with different `sw<>dp`, in order to store different `dp` amounts for scaling sprites on different devices. Should I do this a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the recommended thing to do. You can customize dimensions originally defined in `res/values/dimens.xml` (such as screen margins) for sw720dp devices (e.g. 10" tablets) in landscape in the `res/values-sw720dp-land` for instance.

Comment: np :) glad I could be of help

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good idea.
This is from one of my projects:

[image]

as you can see I have 2 `dimens.xml` files one in `res/values/` folder and the second one in `res/values-w820dp/` folder.

Comment: Yea that comes default for margin attributes. Also Thank you :)